# Query to find sql server services currently running

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Is there any query to find all SQL services currently running on the server including SSRS, SSIS, SSAS?

Comment: Yes Thank you , it is also says to enable xp_cmdshell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If xp_cmdshell is enabled you could run this.

```
CREATE TABLE #WindowsSvc (results VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO #WindowsSvc
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'net start'
SELECT results FROM #WindowsSvc WHERE results LIKE '%SQL Server%'
```

Comment: Thanks this works but is there any way with out enabling xp_cmdshell

Comment: I don't believe there is another way to write T-SQL and acquire that information.  The information you are looking for is outside of SQL server at the Operating System.  xp_cmdshell permits such communication between SQL server and the OS.

Answer (score 2):

The [DBATools](https://dbatools.io/) PowerShell module is very useful for such tasks.

You can use [`Get-DbaService`](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Get-DbaService) function from DBATools to get list of SQL related services installed on one or more servers.

`Get-DbaService -ComputerName YourServer`

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK to use xp_cmdshell you can call tasklist which shows running processes and their process_ids

exec xp_cmdshell "tasklist /FO TABLE"